# why python is not able to import a module even though __init__.py exists

Tags: python

My project has a file system like this

```
test/phx_common_lib/scan/
```

in this directory `__init__.py` file exists along with other file `adfEmulator.py`. I created another python file `collectInjectScan.py` in this directory and I tried to import this in another file as

```
import phx_common_lib.scan.collectInjectScan as collectInjectImage
```

but this is giving error

```
ImportError: No module named collectInjectScan
```

but if I try to import `adfEmulator.py` as below

```
import phx_common_lib.scan.adfEmulator as Emu
```

Can any one please let me know why I am not able to import newly written python file?

Comment: What is the *exact name* of the `__init__.py` file? If it doesn't match what I wrote in this comment (double underscores around `init`, `.py` extension at the end) then it won't work. Your question *title* uses the wrong name!

Comment: Sorry. I edited my question now.

Comment: it should be  `__init__.py`  , as   Martijn Pieters noted, not `__init.py__`

Comment: @omu_negru: You may want to use \` backticks there.

Comment: @ernie: there is a `.` too many in that still.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for the tip.... ctrl+k doesn't do the trick in these boxes it seems :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks. it is indeed __init__.py. I modified the question now.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. There is some fundamental information that is missing. Please try to reproduce the problem in a minimal example. (just create the same directory structure with empty python modules and add only the relevant imports, and try to see whether the problem arises).

Comment: Show full path to files with and without import problem. Are they in the same folder ?

Comment: Is the root directory of the project (`$SOMETHING/test`) in your Python installation's `sys.path` list of locations to search for libraries? Are both of your import attempts from the same location? Python 2 and Python 3 handle relative and absolute import paths differently, so you should also explain exactly which version you're using.

Comment: @Dan I am using python2.6. Root directory exists in sys.path and I am trying to import both modules from the same file (same location)

Comment: Is that location within the project hierarchy itself (`$SOMETHING/test`)? Can you update your question with a **minimal example** that produces the error (presumably two consecutive `import` lines, one for each of the two modules)?

Comment: silly question - does the script have read rights to the new file?

Comment: @ernie yes. The script has read, write permissions.